# Django reverse class based views by function name do not work

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

According to the django docs, viewname is either the function name or the url pattern name. But reversing an url like this 'reverse(MyView.as_view())' turns into a NoReverseMatch exception. Is there any way to reverse class based view by function name?

Answer (score 7):

You can either used [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) or you can do something like the following (in your `views.py`)

```
my_function = MyView.as_view()
```

now reverse will work: `reverse('myviews.my_function')`

Comment: this function trick does not work with current version of django, says that it "is not a valid view function or pattern name"

Comment: In Django v3.1 I got this error `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'myviews.my_function' not found. 'myviews.my_function' is not a valid view function or pattern name`

Comment: @DataGreed: I hope you noticed that your comments come 6 years after the chosen answer. A lot can change in that time. Have you found your answers?