# Django urls.py, what does the name parameter do?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I was poking around my friends project and as I looked through the urls.py file i noticed this:

```
    url(r'^apply/$', contact.as_view(), name='careers_contact'),
```

I just recently learned about class based views, and it all makes sense to me except for the last bit `name='careers_contact'`. I also can't seem to find the meaning of this online.

Can someone shed light on what this is, where that name lives, and what its doing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [`url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#url) `name` parameter

**"What is it? Where does it live?"**

`url()` is simply a function that returns a `django.core.urlresolvers.RegexURLPattern` object, so passing in a `name='careers_contact'` argument sets `name` for that object. None of that is really relevant until this `url(...)` is placed into a [URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#example).

THEN, if we need the URL of a view, we can now get it by passing that `name` into [`{% url 'careers_contact' %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in templates or [`reverse('careers_contact')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) in code and on the backend those functions will use the `name` to map back to the correct URL.

**Why do we need it?**

We  can  reverse the Python Path to get the URL (ex. `reverse(blog.views.home)` ), so what's the point in using `name`?

### [URL Naming](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) and [Namespacing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) allow for 3 things:

- A **simple** way to reverse URL match Class-Based Views. Though it [is possible without it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13193457/3096768).
- A way to [distinguish URL patterns using the same view and parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).
- A way to [differentiate URL names between apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names).

*(Click the links for an example of the issue and how naming/namespacing solves it)*

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response.

Answer (score 3):

The reason they probably added a namespace for the URL is so that they can do reverse namespaced URL.

For example in a template somewhere, you will probably see something like:

```
<a href="{% URL 'contact:careers_contact' %}"> Click me! </a>
```

Comment: I can see it is related to reverse naming. Why is it needed in the urlconf though? What purpose does it hold ? I am a bit confused here