# Django - using reverse() on Class-based views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have the following urls configuration in my Django project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^my-view$', MyViewClass.as_view()),
)
```

Is there a way to use the `reverse()` function to get the url of the above view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django reverse class based views by function name do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193350/django-reverse-class-based-views-by-function-name-do-not-work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there is.

Use the `name` argument of the `url` function to define a name for the url, then you can use `reverse` on this name:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^my-view$', MyViewClass.as_view(), name='my_view'),
)

reverse('my_view')
```

Answer (score -2):

If that `url` requires an argument like:

```
url('<<int:input>>', ClassView.as_view(), name='link')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverlow. Sorry, but your answer is not understandable as it's not even a complete sentence. Please make sure that your posts are gramatically correct with the proper punctuation and formatting.