# How to pass a pattern through the reverse method

Tags: django

Here is my code:

```
views.py

class CollDetailView(DetailView):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
         vote = Vote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(art=self.object,user=self.request.user)
            if vote.id:
                vote_form_url = reverse(
                    'UpdateVote',
                    kwargs={'art_id':vote.art.id,'pk':vote.id})
        else:
            vote_form_url = reverse(
                'CreateVote',
                kwargs={
                    'movie_id':self.object.id}


class UpdateVote(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = VoteForm
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()

class CreateVote(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = VoteForm

urls.py

path('poll/arts/<int:pk>/',
     CollDetailView.as_view(),
     name='art_detail'),
path('poll/arts/<int:art_id>/vote',
     CreateVote.as_view(),
     name='CreateVote'),

path('poll/arts/<int:art_id>/vote',
     UpdateVote.as_view(),
     name='UpdateVote')
```

I get this error:

> Reverse for 'CreateVote' with keyword arguments '{'movie_id': 29}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['poll\/arts\/(?P[0-9]+)\/vote$']

to be honest i am jr and i don't know how to fix that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140133/django-using-reverse-on-class-based-views?rq=1

Comment: Your indentation seemed quite messy (in your original posting, now it has been edited). Do you have it properly indented in your code? It could cause all sorts of trouble if not.

Comment: You **would not** get that error from this code. You would get a NameError, because `self` is not defined at class level. Please show actual code, properly indented, and the real error message.

Comment: (But, of course, this error is because you passed a class rather than a URL pattern name.)

Comment: @IvanStarostin, я исправил по примеру , теперь такого рода ошибка:Reverse for 'UpdateVote' with keyword arguments '{'movie_id': 27}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['poll\\/arts\\/(?P<art_id>[0-9]+)\\/vote$']

Comment: This site is intended only for communication in English. Please update your question with a modified code and new error message. And show your `urls.py`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin,After the fix I get this error

Comment: `'{'movie_id': 29}` vs `poll/arts/<int:art_id>` There is no pattern with `movie_id` parameter here. Also CreateVote and UpdateVote have identical patterns - how will you/your app distinguish between requests to them?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, I am gratefully thankful. these views have different methods. You can check, I correctly use the method reverse ?

Comment: your pattern uses `art_id`, so your `kwargs` in the `reverse` call should be `'art_id'` not `'movie_id'`. Also, as @IvanStarostin mentioned you have defined two patterns for the same URL. So `reverse` will return the URL "poll/arts/29/vote" and then when the user clicks on the link, which of the two patterns is supposed to match? The `CreateVote` or the `UpdateVote` pattern? In this case I believe you will never be able to reach the `UpdateVote` view because Django will always return the first match. Probably your `UpdateVote` url should be `'poll/arts/<int:art_id>/vote/<int:pk>'`

Comment: Not really. There are still no patterns neither for two arguments `art_id + pk` (which you are trying to pass to UpdateVote view), nor for `movie_id`(which you are still trying to pass to CreateVote).

Comment: @dirkgroten,@IvanStarostin thank you very much.you made it working